# android:: how to send two parallel requests and merge the result using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

What I want to achieve is to merge the response of two requests and then update the custom list view.

(Each item in the custom list contains thumbnail image, thus I use volley which I think will help to load images easily.)

Comment: Consider using RxJava